# Project Resource work tracker

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-lightswitch

My manager asked me to create a resource work and project tracker in sharepoint or lightswitch. Is there any default template to do that... Basically I want to add up a team, resource, project, work items, approval flows in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Lightswitch Starter Kits](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch/starter-kits), you could particularly use the **Time Tracker kit** to see projects, teams, and approval flows in action. Then extend it for your needs.